# Header file for included static library not found by swift bridging header during archive

Tags: swift, ios8

I've run into a very vexing problem.

I've included a 3rd party static library (PDFKitten) into my project, which is a mixture of Swift and Objective-C code. I can build & test just fine in simulator and device.

However, when trying to do an Archive build ready to submit to the app store, the Swift compiler complains that the header PDFKitten/PDFKitten.h cannot be found.

Reproducing this is easy:

1. Create an empty Swift iOS project in Xcode.
2. Grab the PDF Kitten project and add it as a sub project.
3. Add the PDFKitten lib as a dependency
4. Create an objective-c source file to force the creation of the bridging header. Once the bridging header is created, you can delete the empty objective-c source file again (not the header!)
5. In the bridging header, add #import

An ordinary build will have no issues.
If you then try to do an archive build you'll get the error message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to get it to archive error-free once I added the path to the "Not Found" header file (in your case, PDFKitten.h) into the Header Search Paths portion of the app's Build Settings.